# Alternative usage of "to sort"

Tags: etymology, word-usage

***To [sort](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sort)*** is  informally used with the meaning of:
​

> [ T ] (uk informal ) to deal with something by repairing or organizing it:
>
> *Can you sort the car by tomorrow?
> We must get the phone sorted soon.
> I must get this paperwork sorted before I go on holiday next week.* (Cambridge Dictionary)

- Where does the above usage come from? It does not seem to be related to the original meaning separating things into groups. The online [etymological dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sort) provides no information about it. Is it common also in American English?

Comment: _Sort_ in this way is sometimes also used as _sort out_. Getting something _sorted out_ means the same as _putting it in order_, which also originally referred to putting since in a certain order. Even _in order_ originally meant _sorted according to size or quality_, but became also _fine, in good shape, all right_. I guess the idea of an ordered situation was seen as a _good_ thing, so that a solved problem became _sorted (out)_.

Comment: "Primary Meanings of
sort 
n 
a category of things distinguished by some common characteristic or quality
2.
vn 
arrange or order by classes or categories" ---https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sort  Now looking at SORT OUT I must state that it is miles away from the primary meaning of SORT. SORT OUT is a Phrasal Verb:
"sort out
1. To separate from others: 
2. To clarify or resolve: 
3. To bring or restore to health or good condition: 
4. To reprimand or punish (someone) for a mistake or offense." see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sort

Comment: Splitting *sort out* with a noun produces interesting Ngrams and is one way to attack this via a search. "sort it out" - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sort_INF+it+out%2C&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Csort_INF%20it%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsort%20it%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorting%20it%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorted%20it%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorts%20it%20out%3B%2Cc0

Comment: sort the problem out - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sort_INF+the+problem+out&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Csort_INF%20the%20problem%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsort%20the%20problem%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorted%20the%20problem%20out%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsorting%20the%20problem%20out%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

The idea of ***sort***  used to refer to   "something out of the desired order" that needs to be fixed, appears to date back to the old expression ***"[out of sorts](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/out-of-sorts.html)"*** which used to refer to   the letters used in typography. The current sense might  have developped out of that usage:

> - Since at least the 17th century 'sorts' has been the name of the letters used by typographers. This usage is referred to in Notes on a Century of Typography at the University Press Oxford 1693–1794 and is nicely defined in Joseph Moxon's Mechanick Exercises, or the Doctrine of Handy-works - Printing, 1683:
>
>   - *"The Letters... in every Box of the Case are... called Sorts in Printers and Founders Language; Thus a is a Sort, b is a Sort.*"

[image]

> - For sets of type blocks to be 'out of sorts' would clearly be unwelcome to a typesetter. That terminology could be the source of the phrase and the notion is certainly a tempting one.

The Phrase Finder

Comment: You seem to be talking only about the noun here, whereas the question asks about the verb _sort [out]_. There's obviously a link between them (and the basic meaning of _sort_ itself), but to answer the question as asked, you'd have to explain that connection.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - the "connection" as I've said might have been  trough usage with that specific meaning. I can't prove it but I think it is a good hint.